# question about constructors in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

Hi
About this partial code in a class which is named Square  :

```
public Square( int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex) 
{
    m_RowIndex = i_RowIndex;
    m_ColIndex = i_ColIndex;
    **new Square(i_RowIndex, i_ColIndex, eCoinType.NoCoin);**
}

public Square(int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex, eCoinType i_CoinType) 
{
    m_RowIndex = i_RowIndex;
    m_ColIndex = i_ColIndex;
    m_Coin = i_CoinType;
}
```

Is it right that it is not good to call an overloaded C'tor within other C'tor and with a "new" statement like you see in bold?
I think this is wrong , and every time we call new we allocate a new instance and it is not right to allocate 2 duplicate instances from C'tor which meant to allocate one instance from the first place.

Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remember: The `new` keyword *always* creates a new object (and a new object isn't the same as any other object which previously existed).

Comment: @pst: FYI as a practical matter the new keyword in an expression does not actually always allocate new storage. If the compiler can determine that the side effects from the modification of a variable that is the destination of a "new" of a value type cannot be observed then the compiler optimizes away the creation of temporary storage and the copy of the new storage to the old variable.  (Of course the new keyword in a member declaration has nothing to do with memory allocation of any kind.)

Comment: @pst: also, of course the new object may very well be the same as an object which has already existed. For example, an implementation of the CLR is permitted to cache and re-use instances of immutable strings as it sees fit. Moreover, suppose you box an int, and then the gc runs and the box goes away, and then you box the same int again. You could end up with the same object in the same memory slot with the same contents. I hope you are not relying upon your false claim that every object instantiation is distinguishable from every other throughout time; that is playing with fire.

Comment: @Eric, useful information as always. Although I knew the CLR permitted re-using instances of immutable strings (this is how interning works, correct?), I never realized the CLR allowed for reusing boxed value types.

Comment: @Harry: It's not that it "allows" it. The memory allocator can sheerly *by accident* place the same contents in the same storage location at two different times, and there's no way to tell the difference between one instance of a "boxed twelve" at location X in the heap and a "different boxed twelve" at the same location five minutes later. The same bits could be copied to the same location twice just by luck.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Thanks for the details. I wasn't trying to imply half of the stuff brought up (SO doesn't seem to be me alerting me on comment replies anymore?). I think a "self-answered" post that contained those details would be really interesting. (I may just be missing the applicable existing SO question).

Comment: @Eric, Gotcha. That makes a lot of sense. Moral of the story, don't rely on specific implementation details of memory management in a managed environment. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't call an overload constructor from within a constructor, that'd create a new instance.

Should be more like:

```
public Square( int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex)
    : this(i_RowIndex, i_ColIndex, eCoinType.NoCoin)
{
}

public Square(int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex, eCoinType i_CoinType) 
{
    m_RowIndex = i_RowIndex;
    m_ColIndex = i_ColIndex;
    m_Coin = i_CoinType;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not right. In fact, this sentence:

```
new Square(i_RowIndex, i_ColIndex, eCoinType.NoCoin);
```

Does **absolutely nothing** (useful) on your constructor.

Comment: Well, it does create a new instance that ends up being GCed.

Comment: @BoltClock: True. But I didn't want to confuse the OP with some non-inheritance-related info. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to go for is something more like this:

```
public Square( int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex) 
    : this(i_RowIndex, i_ColIndex, eCoinType.NoCoin) 
{}

public Square(int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex, eCoinType i_CoinType) 
{
    m_RowIndex = i_RowIndex;
    m_ColIndex = i_ColIndex;
    m_Coin = i_CoinType;
}
```

Calling `new` will create another instance that will just be garbage collected because you don't store a reference to it. Also, m_Coin in the original instance won't be set (or more precisely will be set to `default(eCointType)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Square( int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex) : this(i_RowIndex, i_ColIndex, eCoinType.NoCoin)
{

}

public Square(int i_RowIndex, eColumn i_ColIndex, eCoinType i_CoinType) 
{
            m_RowIndex = i_RowIndex;
            m_ColIndex = i_ColIndex;
            m_Coin = i_CoinType;
}
```